# How accurate is CFD software compared to wind tunnel tests?

Tags: aerodynamics, fluid-dynamics, cfd

How accurate is computational fluid dynamics (CFD) software compared to wind tunnel tests?

(I mean CFD computed with super-computers like the aircraft industry has.)

Comment: Will [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/22852/do-software-simulations-and-wind-tunnel-tests-accurately-predict-cd-and-cl-in-re/22865?r=SearchResults&s=1|93.4871#22865) your question? Please point out where doubts remain.

Comment: yes ,these answers help..

Comment: @PeterKämpf,but in general wind tunnel test gives more accurate results compare to CFD?

Comment: Not necessarily. As I say in that other answer, aeroelasticity is impossible to match in the tunnel (or you need a new model for every data point). Also, the correction factors have only been calculated from earlier models and you only hope they match your test, too. The only accurate data can be achieved in flight test.

Comment: @Peterkampf,if you put aeroelastical wing in tunnel ,devices for lift and drag will show correct results for that tested wing.isnt it?

Comment: Yes, for that tested wing. Which is not the real wing. Good luck measuring the local bending and torsion accurately and changing the results so they fit the bending and torsion of the real wing.

Comment: @PeterKämpf,if we put full size airplane in wind tunnel and make correction for walls ,will reslults will be 100% correct as in real flight?

Comment: Yes, for 100% corrections. When this [was done](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1913/can-you-fly-a-plane-in-a-wind-tunnel), the aircraft had to be held in place by steel cables which also cause differences to real flight. But full-size tests have always helped a lot, especially for drag reduction.